# Creating Columns in a CSV File

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i'm struggling at a code, and I cannot use Pandas. I've looked at other explanations but i think they are hard for me to understand.

```
file=open("Details.csv","a" )
file.append(str"Username" + str"Password" + str"Age" + str"Topic" + 
str"Difficulty" + str"Score"\n)
print("Before we start, we need to register an account.\n")           
User=input(str("Enter your name:\n "))
Age=input("Enter your age:\n")
print("Great! Your username is set to: %s."%(User[0]+User[1]+User[2]+ Age))
Pass=input("Enter a password for your account:\n ")
```

So i'm trying to get 6 columns in a csv file them being, Username, password,age, topic, difficulty and score.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

I went through all the trouble only to not truly answer the scope of your question header. If you use the `csv` module, writing to a .csv is fairly easy. The module writes to the file as iterables (i.e. a list of values). It does so by calling `csv.writer.writerow()`. There is no constraint imposed that the length of the intended headers must equal the length of any iterable you are writing to file.

**Response:**

I'm a big fan of always using the standard library. Inside that library is a module called `csv`. Everything you are trying to do (or at least that you've told us) can be done using this module.

Lets walk through the problem.

First, we will take a look at what you have tried:

```
# you've opened a file for appending (the mode = 'a')
# why do we need to append it? are we assuming that there is already data?
file=open("Details.csv","a" )

# this shouldn't ever work (I dont think ive ever seen this either)
# are these supposed to be headers?
file.append(str"Username" + str"Password" + str"Age" + str"Topic" + 
str"Difficulty" + str"Score"\n)
print("Before we start, we need to register an account.\n")

# okay you are getting a user input
# however, the input() method returns 'str'
# so you dont need to call str() on a 'str'!           
User=input(str("Enter your name:\n "))

# now here if you want an 'int' for the age you call int()
Age=input("Enter your age:\n")
print("Great! Your username is set to: %s."%(User[0]+User[1]+User[2]+ Age))

# why dont you call str() here like you did before?
# is this a different type?
Pass=input("Enter a password for your account:\n ")

# woah, you never do anything with your inputs
# nor do you close the file!
```

Clearly there are a lot of unknowns here. So lets take a look at what you *should* do:

```
import csv

myCSV = '/path/to/Details.csv'
headers = ['Username', 'Password', 'Age', 'Topic', 'Difficulty', 'Score']

# using 'with open()' is called context managing
# with is the context manager
# what this means is when we are done with the file it auto-closes
# I am just going to assume nothing is in the file
# if there is, next time just dont call w.writerow(headers)
with open(myCSV, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    w.writerow(headers)

    # we can drop the '\n' because after print() we go to the next line always
    print("Before we start, we need to register an account.")
    user = input("Enter your name:\n")

    # since you concatenate below, I'll assume you want a 'str'
    age = input("Enter your age:\n")
    print ("Great! Your username is set to: {}".format(user[:3] + age))

    pass = input("Enter a password for your account:\n")

    # then do the same for Topic, Difficulty and Score

    values = [user, pass, age, topic, diff, score]
    w.writerow(values)
```

For the string formatting method, take a glance at [this](https://pyformat.info/) for some updated syntax.

Comment: Wow, i thank you! I really do. I'm still of the essence of python. Also that was a block of the code, that was annoying me so do forgive me i forgot to close the file. I will use this information into account. Thanks again.

Comment: Just one other question, i have a vague idea but not sure entirely. What was " f" mean on the 11 and 12th lines.

Comment: @SRD1707 It is just the syntax alias for the context manager. Think of it as a sentence that reads `"With the file opened with the nickname of F, do the following with F"`. Thus we can do things like `f.read()` and `f.write()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into the `csv` library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and do something in this order

```
with open('Details.csv', 'wb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Username", "Password", "Topic", "Difficulty", "Score"])
```

This will create the column with the header names you specified.